# I keep getting the error "the string did not match the expected pattern" for my fetch request

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

For my fetch requests I keep getting the error:

> "the string did not match the expected pattern".

I've seen some people having similar problems on here and other forums but can't pinpoint the problem.

What is the cause of the error?

```js
function showRecipes(){
    const ingredients = document.getElementById('ingredients').value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    const meal = document.getElementById('meal').value;
    const display = document.getElementById('display'); //Where results will go

    let url = 'http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/';
    url += `?i=${ingredients}&q=${meal}`;

    fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors"})
        .then(response => {
            response.json()
                .then(data => {
                    data.results.forEach(recipe => {
                        const container = document.createElement('div');
                        container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

                        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                        h1.textContent = recipe.title;

                        const p = document.createElement('p');
                        p.textContent = recipe.ingredients;

                        display.appendChild(container);
                        container.appendChild(h1);
                        container.appendChild(p);
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You may get this error if the server's response is text but you attempt to parse it as JSON using `res.json()`.

```
fetch(serverUrl, {method: 'GET'})
.then((res) => res.json())
```

`res.text()` is appropriate if the server returns text.

In this situation Safari once gave me the OP's error, but Chrome was more specific: *"unexpected token W in json at position 0"* -- `res.json()` expects the first character of the string to be `{` or `[` since that is how JSON begins.

Or, as Safari would say, *"the string did not match the expected pattern."*

Comment: I got from the server a `Response` object and your answer put me on the right way.

Answer (score 5):

For those receiving this, and also perhaps debugging their code and finding an HTTP Response object containing information which does not match the information given in the developer tools, this is problem is created by `no-cors`. Remove `no-cors`, and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```js
fetch('example.json').url())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

if the code above returns a status of `200`, and `res.text()` works but `res.json()` does not, then **it's a json formatting issue**, which perhaps the compiler did not recognise the followings:

- reference such as `/**/` or `//`
- comma at end such as `},}` or `],}`
- blanks such as`\t`, `\n`

suggested json pattern is

```js
{"a":"b"}
```

Though following is much better for reading:

```js
{
    "a": "b",
}
```

This issue significantly occurs in **Sublime Text**

Here's a solution:

[GitHub](https://github.com/Weilory/python-json-tidier)

Then try the src followed by:

```js
fetch('example.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Comment: Your answer might not help because it is not a formatting json problem but a problem with a fetch return that is not in json but in text format.

Answer (score 0):

#### An updated example with async/await related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638007/1705829):

```
async function index() {
  var res2 = await fetch('url with text response')

  // res2 is in json format <-- not valid here, see error above in the question
  // var res = await res2.json()

  // res2 is in text format <-- valid here
  var res = await res2.text()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those people getting this error from reading a json file from the local or public folder make sure the file path is preceded correctly. If there is no initial "/" in the file name it's looking at current directory and it may not find the json file. So, instead of:

```
fetch("data.json")
```

try:

```
fetch("/data.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `"The string did not match the expected pattern"` was thrown in JavaScript (using Safari Mobile) when I was setting a DOMNode's `contentEditable` property to `"undefined"` instead of `"true"` or `"false"`. So it would appear this error is thrown when unexpected strings are passed to certain `DOMNode` attributes.